# pyTables / HDF5 performance optimization for slow load times

Tags: python, hdf5, pytables

I am trying to optimize read times for a large HDF5 file created as pyTables table.

The problem has the following features:

- Rows are loaded as batches into a model
- Rows have an id column, which is a csi index
- Rows also have data columns, which each is a large (1,X) tensor (the model inputs), where X is large
- The values in the id column are not unique, instead several rows belong to one unique id
- The model needs to take each row belonging to one id, and aggregate it
- The model can operate on several such unique ids at the same time (as a batch)

The table looks like this:

```
Table:
| id (CSI) | Tensor1    | Tensor2 | ....
|    100   | (0.543,...)| .....   | ....
|    100   | (.....)    | .....   | ....
|    235   | (.....)    | .....   | ....
|    301   | (.....)    | .....   | ....
|    301   | (.....)    | .....   | ....
|    301   | (.....)    | .....   | ....
```

Here is the actual table output format from pyTables

```
dataset.table
File(filename, title='Data File', mode='r', root_uep='/', filters=Filters(complevel=0, shuffle=False, bitshuffle=False, fletcher32=False, least_significant_digit=None))
/ (RootGroup) 'Data File'
/data (Group) 'Data'
/data/table (Table(73040,), shuffle, blosc(9)) 'Table'
  description := {
      "tensor1": Float32Col(shape=(1, 50000), dflt=0.0, pos=0),
      "tensor2": Float32Col(shape=(1, 50000), dflt=0.0, pos=1),
      "id": UInt32Col(shape=(), dflt=0, pos=3)}
  byteorder := 'little'
  chunkshape := (4,)
  autoindex := True
  colindexes := {
    "id": Index(9, full, shuffle, zlib(1)).is_csi=True}
```

Currently the id is not consecutive (this is an easy change if it helps) but it is sorted and fully indexed!

I have written a dataloader class that loads and aggregates a batch. A batch is any successive set of unique ids. 
In the above example, a batch of size 2 would be for example `[100,235]`.
So my idea was to load many rows at once, keeping track of ids in a separate vector, and aggregating later.

To load from pyTables, I tried two options, either querying single IDs

```
for single_ids in batch:
    query = "".join(['(id==', str(single_id), ')'])
    row = self.data.read_where(query)
    (concat rows etc)...
```

or querying the whole batch by limits (note that the ID column is sorted!)

```
limits = [batch[0],batch[-1]
query = "".join(['(id>=', str(limits[0]), ') & (id<=', str(limits[1]), ')'])
rows = self.data.read_where(query)
```

pyTables confirms that both queries are indexed on the id column.
I tried with and without compression.
I also use threading to load this in the background.
Chunking is set to auto, as the amount of rows per unique id varies (Average is 7, autochunk determined 4). This currently runs on a SSD.

The bottleneck of my whole model is this loading of data. Querying the pyTables database in this fashion seems to be very slow. With about 70k rows, the whole operation takes around 70 to 90 seconds, which almost completely is due to the loading of data.

I wonder whether what I am doing is inefficient.
First, the lazy loading of the queries (when it occurs) is slow, so it seems that is an IO issue or the way I query.

Perhaps there is a faster way to step through the whole table. I could save the indecies that belong to each unique ID, and query them in succession. But I had hoped that, well, a table index would do exactly this.

Perhaps it is inefficient to have a table of tensors?
Should I transform each tensor into an EArray, where the first column corresponds to ID, or where a separate table saves the indecies? Would that be faster?

Edit:
I have redone everything, now letting the unique ids be nodes in the hierarchy, each having its own table.
To iterate through the sample in batches, this is about **twice as slow** as my solution above.

Any ideas on how to speed this up would be grand!

Comment: Or do you think I should store each unique id as separate _node_ in the table and then iterate over nodes??

Comment: To be clear, I am experimenting, but it is quite costly, so I am looking to what the best direction would be!

Comment: I frequently use PyTables `read_where()`, `get_where_list()`, and `where()` functionality. I have found it to be very fast (I've never had to benchmark or optimize performance). My tables can have >1e6 rows, are not indexed, and have a mix of strings, ints, and floats. Some may be small ndarrays (say [10]). Note: `.read_where(query)` returns a NumPy record array with the rows that match the query (aka condition).  Have you done any performance tests with the `read_where` process isolated from the rest of your program?

Comment: I am profiling the queries in the program, and informally I also run them outside of the program with test queries. Does not seem to be much difference between them. What do you think I should be looking for?

Comment: I also believe pyTables to be very fast in querying, but I just wonder whether I have made a mistake in setting up the database. It may of course be that due to the size of my ndarrays, it just simply can not be done fast..

Comment: There are 2 operations with `read_where()`. First there is the query ("where"), and then the data is "read" into a NumPy record array. It's hard to say which is the bottleneck. You can separate these 2 steps by using `get_where_list()` to query for a list of rows that satisfy the condition. Then you can read these rows with `read_coordinates()` referencing the list returned from `get_where_list()`. This should isolate the bottleneck: query or reading the data.